# What to pay for an initial patent submission?

Tags: filing, application, uspto, pro-se

I am submitting a patent application to be filed. The USPTO asks to tick appropriate services

```
Filing | Search | Exam
```

Do I need to select and pay all of them at this stage OR *for example* `Exam` is needed after completing the `Search` step?

Do I need to pay all items for a new patent submission?

NOTE: Please do not advise to hire a patent attorney, as I wish to learn/do the process by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pay all three in order for your application to move forward. They are listed separately in the fee schedule but, other than for one very specific case, it is best to think of them as one fee. The fees do not need to be paid at the time of filing but if not paid then there is a surcharge and you will get a notice that it must be paid by a certain date - usually a month or two after the date.

I would recommend that you get the book "[Patent it yourself](http://amzn.to/2jV4pr4)". Patenting is a deep, subtle and confusing field but with that you have a fighting chance.

Comment: Great point about surcharges!  They can be very costly, especially for a solo inventor.